# affine plane from finite field

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am trying to prove that we can construct a finite affine plane from a finite field $GF(n)$ where $n $ is a prime power. I am having trouble with proving the Playfair's axiom, i.e. given any line $l$ and a point not on $l$ there is a unique line through the point that has empty intersection with $l$.

Let $F$ be a finite field. Let the point set be $F \times F$, and lines to be the set of solutions to equations $ax + by + c = 0$, where not both $a$ and $b$ are zero. I am given a line $ax + by + c = 0$ and a point $(\alpha, \beta)$ not on this line. Also it can be checked that $ax + by + (-a\alpha -b\beta) =0$ contains the given point and has empty intersection with the given line. However, I am having trouble with proving the uniqueness of this parallel line. Can anyone help? Thank you!

Comment: The lines parallel to $ax+by+c=0$ have equations of the form $ax+by+d=0$. For how many choices of $d$ will the point $(\alpha,\beta)$ satisfy that equation?

Comment: You need that if $a'x+b'y+c'=0$ doesn't meet $ax+by+c=0$ then $(a,b)$ is not a scalar multiple of $(a',b')$.